# Data sharing between nodejs micro services using events

Tags: node.js, events, microservices

So I am having a micro service architecture for my project, were I have like 2-3 services running. I need to call in an action based on some events that triggered on these services.

How can I achieve that, using nodejs event emitter class, or any other similar services. 
Is socket.io an alternative?

Or is it even possible?

Comment: If theses are the type of micro services I think they are, then they're in separate processes and you can't use an eventEmitter to communicate between them.  An eventEmitter is for within a single node.js process.  You would have to use some sort of interprocess communication to communicate info between microservices (http requests, webSocket or socket.io messages, nodejs child process `sendMessage()`, etc....  If your microservices are all within the same node.js process, then you can use eventEmitter events to share data.

Comment: whats amount of data to be handled ? expecting throughput?  want your services to be Scalable & Fault tolerant ?

Comment: it's basically some sort of log writing, but not exactly that. We call a function from one service but the function body is in another service, and its called from multiple services. And all of them are hosted separately.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant events (that you need for communication betwenn your distributed services) need to be part of the "public" api of your microservice.
So the service that throws (domain) events can either offer same pub/sub mechanism or you use a message oriented middleware (RabbitMQ, Kafka,...)
In your microservice you can have an interface service that subscribes to the internal triggered events and then retrigger the relevant ones to this public api..

Comment: do we need to have a parent like service?